# setState() called after dispose(): _LoginState#f1cba(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm getting this error while in my login logic I've created

Here is the [Sentry report](https://sentry.io/share/issue/f29225263742439fb75c4a7fe32baf70/) of this issue, and here is the code I've used :

```dart
  Future<void> fetchingData() async {
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
      _isLoading = true;
    setState(() {});
    String theUrl;
    List users = await APIServices().doTheLogin();
    OUTER:
    for (var element in users) {
      if (element['username'] == userNameTextController.text &&
          element['password'] == passwordTextController.text) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        prefs.setString('the_url', element['domain']['domain']);
        theUrl = 'http://${element['domain']['domain']}';
        int theCode =
            await CheckIfOnlineServices(theUrl: theUrl).checkIfOnline();
        if (theCode == 200) {
          List employees =
              await APIServices(theUrl: theUrl).getEmployeeDetails();
          INNER:
          for (var singleEmployee in employees) {
            if (singleEmployee['user_name'] == userNameTextController.text &&
                singleEmployee['password'] == passwordTextController.text) {
              try {
                prefs.setString(
                    'branch_url', singleEmployee['shift']['branch']['url']);
                prefs.setString(
                    'branch_id', singleEmployee['shift']['branch']['id'].toString());
                prefs.setString('employee_name', singleEmployee['name']);
                prefs.setString('employee_url', singleEmployee['url']);
                prefs.setString('password', singleEmployee['password']);

                if (singleEmployee['can_buy']) {
                  prefs.setInt('can_buy', 1);
                } else {
                  prefs.setInt('can_buy', 0);
                }
                if (singleEmployee['can_collect_money']) {
                  prefs.setInt('can_collect_money', 1);
                } else {
                  prefs.setInt('can_collect_money', 0);
                }
                prefs.setString(
                    'branch_name', singleEmployee['shift']['branch']['name']);
                await prefs.setInt('is_online', 1);
                await APIServices(theUrl: theUrl).getCategories();
                await APIServices(theUrl: theUrl).getProducts();
                await APIServices(theUrl: theUrl).getCompanyData();
                await APIServices(theUrl: theUrl).checkEmployeeIn();
                await SaveCompanyLogo().saveImage();
                String employeeName = (prefs.getString('employee_name'));
                String branchName = (prefs.getString('branch_name'));
                Shift _shift = Shift(
                    startTime: DateTime.now(),
                    branchName: branchName,
                    employeeName: employeeName);
                await ShiftService().startShift(_shift);
                //await ConsumablesService().gettingConsumablesData();
                //await AdditionService().fetchingAdditionData();
                //wait RecipieServices().fetchRecipieData();
                await Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/gateway');
                break INNER;
              } catch (shiftError) {
                  _isLoading = false;
                  _badLogin = false;
                  setState(() {});
                Alert(
                  context: context,
                  type: AlertType.error,
                  title: "لم يتم تخصيص وردية لهذا الموظف",
                  desc: "يجب تخصيص وردية للموظف قبل البدأ فى استعمال البرنامج",
                  buttons: [
                    DialogButton(
                      child: Text(
                        "موافق",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      width: 120,
                    )
                  ],
                ).show();
                return;
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          await prefs.setInt('is_online', 0);
          Alert(
            context: context,
            type: AlertType.error,
            title: "لا يوجد إتصال باالسيرفر الرئيسى",
            desc:
                "لن تحصل على تحديثات الاصناف من السيرفر الرئيسى و لن يتم ارسال تقارير مبيعاتك حتى تتصل بالسيرفر .",
            buttons: [
              DialogButton(
                child: Text(
                  "موافق",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                ),
                onPressed: () async {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                width: 120,
              )
            ],
          ).show();
        }
        break OUTER;
      }
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 20), () {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
          _badLogin = true;
        });
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3),() {
          _badLogin = false;
          setState(() {});
        });
      });
    }
    ;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simply ripped every `Setstate` and `Future.delayed()` inside

```dart
if (mounted) {
// your logic here 
}
```

And the errors are gone !!